# Feature based alignment & Non linear least square

Tags: math, computer-vision

> Computer vision: Algorithims and Applications (Szeliski)

In this book at the chapter **"Feature Based Alignment" 6.1.3 Iterative Algorithims** 
 There is a term "**ri**" which I don't know how to calculate. Here it is the snip from book.

People who are in to computer vision may know this method very well. This is why I am asking this question in here instead of a math forum.

---

[image: szeliski nonlinear least square]

Comment: I'm sure it is defined in the book

Answer (score 0):

r_i is the residual between the measured location and the corresponding current predicted location  as defined in the book. Read the chapter again, from the beginning...
This is not a reading service.